# FitNesse: Can't see the difference between the expected and the actual result in failed assertion

Tags: fitnesse

I'm using FitNesse to test web service responses using `check` to compare the expected to the actual response.

In some cases the check is failing and I can't see what the differences are between the expected and the actual that is causing it to fail.

Here's a screenshot from what it's telling me in a specific instance (of many similar instances):
[image: Here's an example where it's failing and I can't see why]

Feel free to point out the obvious; it's probably staring at me in the face and I'm looking so hard I can't see it!

Comment: Same `toString()`, but `equals()` returns false.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your string contains extra spaces in the actual value.  FitNesse, being html based, will not respect leading or trailing spaces.  It might not handle any extra spaces inside the actual either.  So this can cause the result to be different, but not visibly so.

See if you can add some debug messages that would help you see the extra spaces, or at least count the number of characters in both strings.

Answer (score 1):

I would check that the expected and actual strings are both written with the same text encoding. I've seen this error plenty of times when the text comparing failed due to a comma or apostrophe being written in different encodes.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't specify whether Slim or Fit are being used, or which Slim server/plugin if using Slim, but I found the following to be true for me using FitNesse release *20130530* and fitSharp release *2.2*:

1. Non-ASCII characters and { apostrophes / single quote characters } in input arguments/parameters that are strings are HTML encoded. The values in my FitNesse test tables are HTML encoded, but only the required syntax characters and (double) quotes; not the non-ASCII characters (and FitNesse doesn't seem to have any problems storing those values).
2. EOL characters in the input arguments that are strings consist of a linefeed character only
3. I imagine that because I'm using .NET, EOLs in my return values consist of carriage return and linefeed characters.

Because of [1], I'm HTML-encoding non-ASCII characters (but not the HTML syntax characters or quotes). Because of [2] and [3], I'm now removing carriage return characters from my fixture return values. Both changes seem to have resolved this issue for me and expected and actual values are now reported as being the same.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace has troubled me often. The resulting HTML just collapses whitespace, but the compare in code does not. 
I now use a fixture to make differences more explicit to me. Example usage: http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.CompareFixtureTest.html

Newer versions of FitNesse (since 20151230) do a diff on the expected and actual result values. Has that helped you at all?